# OpenGL model, view, projection matrices

Tags: c, opengl, matrix

I am trying to understand cameras in opengl that use matrices.

I've written a simple shader that looks like this:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 a_col;

uniform mat4 u_mvp_mat;
uniform mat4 u_mod_mat;
uniform mat4 u_view_mat;
uniform mat4 u_proj_mat;

out vec4 f_color;

void main()
{
    vec4 v = u_mvp_mat * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position =   u_mvp_mat * vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
    //gl_Position =   u_proj_mat * u_view_mat * u_mod_mat * vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
    f_color = a_col;
}
```

It's a bit verbose but that's because I am testing passing in either the model, view or projection matrices and doing the multiplication on the gpu or doing the multiplication on the cpu and passing in the mvp matrix and then just doing the mvp * position matrix multiplication.

I understand that the later one can offer performance increase but drawing 1 quad I don't really see any issues with performance at this point.

Right now I use this code to get the locations from my shader and create the model view and projection matrices.

```
pos_loc = get_attrib_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "a_pos");
col_loc = get_attrib_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "a_col");
mvp_matrix_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_mvp_mat");
model_mat_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_mod_mat");
view_mat_loc = get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_view_mat");
proj_matrix_loc =
    get_uniform_location(ce_get_default_shader(), "u_proj_mat");

float h_w = (float)ce_get_width() * 0.5f;  //width = 320
float h_h = (float)ce_get_height() * 0.5f; //height = 480

model_mat = mat4_identity();
view_mat = mat4_identity();
proj_mat = mat4_identity();

point3* eye = point3_new(0, 0, 0);
point3* center = point3_new(0, 0, -1);
vec3* up = vec3_new(0, 1, 0);

mat4_look_at(view_mat, eye, center, up);
mat4_translate(view_mat, h_w, h_h, -20);

mat4_ortho(proj_mat, 0, ce_get_width(), 0, ce_get_height(), 1, 100);

mat4_scale(model_mat, 30, 30, 1);

mvp_mat = mat4_identity();
```

after this I setup my vao and vbo's then get ready to do rendering.

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(ce_get_default_shader()->shader_program);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

mvp_mat = mat4_multi(mvp_mat, view_mat, model_mat);
mvp_mat = mat4_multi(mvp_mat, proj_mat, mvp_mat);

glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(mvp_mat));

glUniformMatrix4fv(model_mat_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(model_mat));
glUniformMatrix4fv(view_mat_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(view_mat));
glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(proj_mat));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, quad->vertex_count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Assuming that all the matrix math is correct, I would like to abstract view and projection matrix out into a camera struct as well as the model matrix into a sprite struct so that I can avoid all this matrix math and make things easier to use.

The matrix multiplication order is:

```
Projection * View * Model * Vector
```

so the camera would hold the projection and view matrices while the sprite holds the model matrix.

Do all your camera transformations and your sprite transformations then right before you send the data to the gpu you do your matrix multiplications.

If I remember correctly matrix multiplication isn't commutative so doing
`view * projection * model` will result in the wrong resulting matrix.

pseudo code

```
glClearxxx(....);
glUseProgram(..);
glBindVertexArray(..);

mvp_mat = mat4_identity();
proj_mat = camera_get_proj_mat();
view_mat = camera_get_view_mat();
mod_mat  = sprite_get_transform_mat();

mat4_multi(mvp_mat, view_mat, mod_mat); //mvp holds model * view
mat4_multi(mvp_mat, proj_mat, mvp_mat); //mvp holds proj * model * view

glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_mat, 1, GL_FALSE, mat4_get_data(mvp_mat));

glDrawElements(...);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Is that a performant way to go about doing this that is scalable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that a performant way to go about doing this that is scalable?

Yes, unless you have a very exotic use case of some sort which is very unlike the norm.

The last thing you should typically ever be worrying about is with respect to the performance of retrieving a modelview and projection matrix out of a camera.

It's because those matrices typically only need to be fetched once per frame per viewport. There's millions of iterations worth of other work that could occur in a frame while scanline-rasterizing primitives, and pulling matrices out of a camera is just a simple constant-time operation.

So typically you want to just make it as convenient as you like. In my case, I go all the way through an abstract interface of function pointers in a central SDK, at which point the functions then *compute* the proj/mv/ti_mv matrix on the fly out of user-defined properties associated with the camera. In spite of this, it never shows up as a hotspot -- it doesn't even show up in the profiler at all.

There's far more expensive things to worry about. Scalability implies scale -- the complexity of retrieving matrices out of camera doesn't scale. The number of triangles or quads or lines or other primitives you want to render could scale, the number of fragments processed in a frag shader can scale. Cameras typically don't scale except with respect to the number of viewports, and no one should ever have use for a million viewports.

Comment: I got your point about scalability and it does make sense. One more question though. Let's say I do like you recommend and make the camera return a view * projection matrix, wouldn't then multiplying by the model matrix produce the wrong result since it would be say `model * proj * view` and that's not the proper way to do matrix multiplication. I guess it could be possible to pass the model matrix to the camera and have that do the right thing but then it would make the sprite tie really close to the camera, no?

Comment: Or I'd suggest, from a camera interface level, return projection and modelview matrices. The rest you can calculate on site when rendering against the camera (ex: transposed inverse modelview for normal computation).

Comment: As for multiplying matrices in the right order, yes -- you have to do that. But I am not quite sure why that's a concern here -- just multiply them in the order needed to get the correct results.. or am I missing something that makes that difficult to do?

Comment: I initially thought that I could return the model view and projection matricies from the camera but that would required me to somehow pass the model matrix to the camera in order to have the proper matrix multiplication order. I think for now the best approach would be to return the projection and view matrix from the camera in the render function do the multiplication in place and pass the results to the shader.

Comment: Oh I see -- but here I think there's a mix-up between low-level and high-level concerns of a "camera". If your camera is anything even remotely like a real-world camera, then it has a position and orientation (captured in the modelview matrix) in the world in addition to properties defining its characteristics like field of view (captured in the projection matrix). So a proper camera kind of object should typically be able to store the information necessary for the modelview matrix at all times -- you shouldn't have to pass it in.

Comment: Typically with a camera object you want to be able to do stuff with it like move it around, make it look at something specific, adjust the zoom, pan it, orbit around a scene, etc. To do that requires the camera to be able to store enough information to provide a modelview matrix on its own (either computed or directly provided). So there might be something odd about the way you're looking at the design of a camera in general if you feel tempted to store the modelview matrix outside and pass it in -- the camera should have the responsibility of storing and updating it and returning it.

Comment: Also for flexibility, you typically want the camera to return the modelview and projection matrix *separately*. Let the rendering code worry about multiplying the resulting matrices in the proper order as required for the shader -- let the camera worry about maintaining those two matrices properly as the user tries to navigate around the scene.

Comment: thanks that's the last little bit that I was a little unsure about. I understand that the camera needs to at least have 2 matrices as well as position and rotation for the x,y,z axis as well as scale and some other things as well. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Cheers -- though that other answer is also great in terms of the actual things you'll need to concern yourself with when it comes to performance and scalability (cameras and mv/proj matrices typically aren't one of them).

Comment: @Ike That's a fine answer of yours. I find it's a quality question well suited to *condense* some basics about the whys and what-abouts of strategic OpenGL design and implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked that bit-wise, but it generally looks ok what you're doing.

> I would like to abstract view and projection matrix out into a camera struct

That's a most appropriate idea; I can hardly imagine a serious GL application without such an abstraction

> Is that a performant way to go about doing this that is scalable?

General constraints of scalability are

- diffuse and specular [**BRDFs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_reflectance_distribution_function) (which also require, btw, a light uniform, a normal attribute and calculation of a normal matrix [if the scaling of the model is non-uniform](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/)) and need [**per-pixel illumination**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Smooth_Specular_Highlights) for quality rendering.
- same with multiple lights (e.g. the sun and a close spotlight)
- shadow maps! shadow maps? (one for each light-source?)
- transparency
- reflections (mirrors, glass, water)
- textures

As you may take it from the list, you will not get very far with just an MVP uniform and a vertex coordinate attribute.

But the mere number of uniforms is by far not the most crucial points for performance - seeing your code I'm positive that you will not recompile your shaders unnecessarily, update your uniforms only if needed, use [*Uniform Buffer Objects*](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) etc..

**The issue is the data that is plugged into those uniforms and VBOs. Or not.**

---

Consider humanoid mesh "Alice" running (that's a mesh morph + translation) across a city square on a windy (water will have ripples) evening (more than one relevant light source), passing a fountain.

Lets' consider we collect it all for by all means on the CPU and old-school only plug ready-to render data into the shaders:

- Alice's mesh is morphed, thus her VBOs need an update
- Alice's mesh will move; thus all affected shadow maps will need an update (*OK, given. they are generated by shadow illumination loops on the GPU, but if you do the wrong way you will shove a lot of data around*)
- Alice's reflection in the fountain will come and go
- Alice's hair will be swirled - the CPU may have quiet a busy time, to say the least

(in  fact the latter is so difficult that you will hardly see any halfway-realistic real-time long open hair animation, but amazingly (*no, not really*)  many pony-tails and short hair cuts)

And we've not yet talked about Alice's attire; let's just hope she's wearing a t-shirt and a jeans (not wide shirt and a skirt, which would require fall-of-the-folds and collision calculations).

As you may have guessed that old-school approach doesn't take us far and thus, there is a fit to be found between between CPU and GPU operations.

In addition, one should think about parallelization of calculations at an early stage. It is advantageous to have the data **as flat as possible in chunks as large as reasonable**, so one just puts a pointer and size into a gl-call and bids that data farewell without any copying, re-arranging, looping or further ado.

That's my 2 cents of wisdom for today about GL performance and scalability.

Comment: the points you bring up in this answer is actually what initially brought me to write this question. While it seems very far away from my current implementation, I would prefer to avoid digging myself into a ditch. There's a lot of things to think about, thank you and I upvoted this answer.